# Route [store] not defined. Larvel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a simple laravel 8 registration page. I got the error was **Route [store] not defined. (View: F:\laravelp\crud\blog\resources\views\Index.blade.php)** what I tried so far I attached below enclosed with the screenshot image
[image]

**index.blade.php**

```
 <form action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST">
       @csrf
            
         <div class="form-group">
          <div  class="col-sm-12">
                   <h2 style="text-align: center; color: blue">Student Details</h2>
           </div>
            </div>
            
            <hr/>
                    <div class="row">
                       
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                           <label>Student Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="studname" class="form-control" id="stname" placeholder="Student Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                           <label>Course</label>
            <input type="text" name="course" class="form-control" id="course" placeholder="Course">
                        </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                           <label>Fee</label>
            <input type="text" name="fee" class="form-control" id="fee" placeholder="Fee">
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group col-md-6" align="center"> 

                        <Button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 80px;">Submit</Button>
              
                        </div>
            </div>
            
        </form>
        <div>
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('index', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'store']);
```

**StudentController**

```
  public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }
    
   
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'studname' => 'required',
            'course' => 'required',
            'fee' => 'required',

        ]);
    
        Student::create($request->all());
     
        return redirect()->route('index')
                        ->with('success','Student created successfully.');
    }
```

Comment: Your `Route::post('index', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'store']);` needs to be `Route::post('index', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'store'])->name('store');` as you are using a route name, but have not set it.

Comment: sir it working again have one problem after add the records i got the error  Route [index] not defined.

Comment: this line how to set the route   return redirect()->route('index')
                        ->with('success','Student created successfully.');

Comment: Same issue... `->name('index')` on your other route.

Comment: how to do it sir

Comment: Exactly the same way as you fixed your first issue... **Add `->name('index')` to the other route**

Comment: i add the like this way Route::post('index', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'index'])->name('index'); but Route [store] not defined

Comment: Route::post('/', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'index'])->name('index'); i tried like this working but Student created successfully message didn't displayed y

Comment: That's a completely separate issue. Please limit your question to a single question, and if you have a follow-up, ask a new question. The answer below should be upvoted and/or accepted when you get the chance.

Comment: ok thanks sir workingggggg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{{route('store')}} means route name. So you need to give a name to your route.

```
Route::post('index', [App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::class, 'store'])->name('store')
```

Comment: sir it working again have one problem after add the records i got the error Route [index] not defined this line how to set the route return redirect()->route('index') ->with('success','Student created successfully.');

Comment: It's the same problem. Index is the route name not the path. BTW, this is so confusing. You have "/index" named store, and "/" names index. Why is that? Keep a route and its name similar to make it cleanar. Instead of /index use /store and make "/" route's name index.